# Google Maps with OMS - Marker properties in response to click event

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a bit of a problem with [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) for the Google Maps API:

Near the start of the script, I store all of my markers in an array called "parentNodes". When I click on a marker, I need to be able to detect the "id" of that marker ("id" is a property of each marker that I set whenever I was initialising them) so that I can run another function that hides all of the markers except for the one that I clicked on.

I've tried adding a listener for each marker after I initialise them, but it wouldn't recognise the array, even though it's global, giving me the error "parentNodes[i] is undefined" whenever I clicked on a marker.

```
for(var i = 0; i < parentNodes.length; i++)
            {
                oms.addListener('click', function()
                {
                    console.log(parentNodes[i].id);
                });
            }
```

I was thinking that a better solution would be just to have the one listener, but is there a way of accessing the properties of a marker if the listener doesn't know which one was clicked on and only whether or not were other markers underneath it? Or does the listener know somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This is a FAQ (usually about infowindows initialized in a loop).  "i" is greater than parentNodes.length, so parentNodes[i] is undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...I'm initialising the parentNodes array in a different function that's called before this one but that uses the same "for" loop. Shouldn't parentNodes[i] here just refer to an element of the global array that I've already initialised? Is this something to do with closures?

Comment: Set a break point in your code where it is outputting the undefinded error, see what the value of "i" is.  You asked: `Is this something to do with closures?` Probably.